# Parsing JSON and Converting in List Of Object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I have a json response received from API Call the sample response is something like this

```
{
 "meta": {
   "code": "200"
  },
 "data": [
   {
    "Id": 44,
    "Name": "Malgudi ABC"
  },
  {
    "Id": 45,
    "Name": "Malgudi, DEF"
  }
]
}
```

I am trying to make List of Object from it, the code that i've written for this is

```
private static List<TPDetails> getListOfTpDetails(ResponseEntity<?> responseEntity){
       ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<TPDetails> tpDetailsList = objectMapper.convertValue(responseEntity.getBody().getClass(), new TypeReference<TPDetails>(){});
        return tpDetailsList;
    }
```

Where TPDetails Object is Like this

```
public class TPDetails {
    int Id;
    String Name;
}
```

the code which i have used is resulting in

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unrecognized field "meta" (class com.sbo.abc.model.TPDetails), not marked as ignorable (2 known properties: "Id", "Name"])
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.sbo.abc.model.TPDetails["meta"])
```

I want to convert the Above JSON response in List

```
List<TPDetails> abc = [
{"Id": 44, "Name": "Malgudi ABC"},
{"Id": 45,"Name": "Malgudi DEF"}
]
```

Any help would be highly appreciable.Thanks well in advance

Comment: What libraries are you wanting to use, or do you have no preference?

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 more  classes like

```
public class Temp {
    Meta meta;
    List<TPDetails> data;
}

public class Meta {
    String code;
}
```

and now convert this json to Temp class.

```
Temp temp = objectMapper.convertValue(responseEntity.getBody().getClass(), new TypeReference<Temp>(){});
```

UPDATED :

Make sure `responseEntity.getBody()` return the exact Json String which you mentioned above.

```
Temp temp = objectMapper.readValue(responseEntity.getBody(), new TypeReference<Temp>(){});
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.sbo.abc.model.TPWrapper["data"])
null, is what i'm getting while parsing the data

Comment: @NTanwar use `responseEntity.getBody()` instead of `responseEntity.getBody().getClass()`. and are you sure `convertValue` is the function you want to use. I think `readValue` is the function

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'readValue(capture<?>, anonymous com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference<com.sbo.abc.model.TPWrapper>)'
is what i am getting
TPWrapper class is like this


```
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "meta",
        "data"
})
public class TPWrapper {

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("meta")
    TPMeta meta;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    List<TPDetails> data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The format of your java class does not reflect the json you are parsing. I think it should be:

```
class Response {
    Meta meta;
    List<TPDetails> data;
}

class Meta {
    String code;
}
```

You should then pass `Response` to your `TypeReference`: `new TypeReference<Response>(){}`

If you don't care about the `meta` field, you can add `@JsonIgnoreProperties`
 to your response class and get rid of the `Meta` class and field.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.sbo.abc.model.TPWrapper["data"])
null

is something which i have got

Comment: @NTanwar do you have getters, setters and empty constructor on the classes?

Comment: @Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "meta",
        "data"
})
public class TPWrapper {

    @JsonIgnoreProperties("meta")
    TPMeta meta;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    List<TPDetails> data;
}


i am using lombok and annotations, so need not to write it explicitly

Comment: I have noticed now, why are you using the `convertValue` method instead of the `readValue`? Also, I have added this configuration to the objectmapper and it working properly: `objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)`

Answer (score 0):

Create/update following class, I am storing JSON file, since do not have service, but should be fine and Able to parse it and read it from the following model.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

import java.util.List;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "meta",
        "data"
})
public class OuterPoJo {

    @JsonProperty("meta")
    private Meta meta;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private List<TPDetails> data = null;

    @JsonProperty("meta")
    public Meta getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

    @JsonProperty("meta")
    public void setMeta(Meta meta) {
        this.meta = meta;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public List<TPDetails> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    @JsonProperty("data")
    public void setData(List<TPDetails> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "code"
})
public class Meta {

    @JsonProperty("code")
    private String code;

    @JsonProperty("code")
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @JsonProperty("code")
    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

}

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "Id",
        "Name"
})
public class TPDetails {

    @JsonProperty("Id")
    private Integer id;
    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("Id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Id")
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}


import java.io.File;
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    OuterPoJo myPoJo = objectMapper.readValue(
            new File("file.json"),
            OuterPoJo.class);

    for (TPDetails item : myPoJo.getData()) {
        System.out.println(item.getId() + ":" + item.getName());
    }

}
}
```

output:

```
44:Malgudi ABC
45:Malgudi, DEF
```